# How to used the Reserved Product IDs in testing In App Billing

Tags: android, testing, xamarin.android, in-app-billing

I wanted to use the Reserved Product IDs like `android.test.purchased` but then when I passed that Product ID's it says "this item is not available for purchase".
I did like this:

```
var iapService = DependencyService.Get<IIAPService>();
iapService.Purchase("android.test.item_unavailable");
```

But then I tried to pass the parameter with the product ID I've created in the In App products at google play store.

```
    var iapService = DependencyService.Get<IIAPService>();
    iapService.Purchase("myapp.product1");
```

I could not proceed since I don't have credit card and when i tried to use the test credit cards number like 4111111111111111 for VISA, still I could not proceed with the transaction. It always says that "Correct this card or try a different card.

Is there anything I can do for the testing? How to use the Reserved Product IDs? Why is it not functioning to my case?

Thank you in advance for the help.